# Access unsplash APi using R

Tags: r, api, get

I'd like to first search for photos and then download them from the unsplash api. However, I must have something wrong...

```
library(httr)
unsplash_url <- "https://api.unsplash.com" 
request_url <- "/search/photos?page=1&query=office"

my_response <- httr::GET(unsplash_url, query = request_url)
my_response
Response [https://unsplash.com/developers]
  Date: 2022-08-22 12:24
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size: 159 kB
```

According to the documentation the Status means ok.

However, I can't extract the identification number from this object:

```
response$content
[1] 0a 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 ...
```

Adding `&client_id=MY_ACCESS_KEY` to `request_url` does not change any of the output..
How can I extract the ids?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @mrflick - using the query differently does provide the output correctly:

```
my_query <- list(page=1, query="office", client_id="XXX"); 
my_response <- httr::GET(unsplash_url, query = my_query)
my_response
Response [https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=office&client_id=XXX]
  Date: 2022-08-22 20:26
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 36.9 kB

id1 <- pluck(content(my_response), "results", 1, "id")
```

Comment: To parse the content returned by `httr` you use `content(my_response)`. It looks like it's sending back an HTML page.

Comment: Also it looks like you are not using the URL and query correctly. It should look more like this: `unsplash_url <- "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos"; my_query <- list(page=1, query="office"); my_response <- httr::GET(unsplash_url, query = my_query)`